# WinForms "mini-windows"

Tags: winforms

I need to create some mini-windows, like the ones shown in the image bellow, in my winform main form.

It would be nice if they could be draggable, resizable, and, mainly, closable.
How can I approach this design? Has anybody already seen some control (with code available) implementing something similar?

[alt text http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/5765/imagea.png](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/5765/imagea.png)

Comment: Check out DockPanel Suite: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal `Form` works fine for this. Set its `FormBorderStyle` to either `FixedToolWindow` or `SizableToolWindow` as desired.

If you want to keep your floating windows inside your main window, use MDI (Multiple Document Interface). Here is a [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx) (Google can find you many more).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The problem now is that I have a Graphics object created from a control that is in the MDI Parent. When I open the child MDI frame, the graphics control get over the opened window. I played with some frame properties, but I couldn't get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property to [SizeableToolWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx)?

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You can create them as resizable and draggable custom controls.

You could use my example at:

http://hourlyapps.blogspot.com/2008/07/resizable-and-movable-controls-c-net.html